# horizontal swipe list of elements like on "Google Films" search results

Tags: javascript, html, slider, swipe, drag

Is there a github or open source project which is a horizontal slider/swiper like on the google Films page?

[image: Google Film Screenshot]

Live Demo: https://www.google.at/search?q=films
I did a research but could not found the same behavior because this swiper does not force you to drag, on the desktop, you also can use the vertical scroll wheel and if you use the next button, it jumps to the next x elements and calculates how much it can skip depending on the screen size. Also the elements does not snap in place which is great I think, if you swipe. The cover is under your fingertip and moves as you swipe and does not do an animation or moves and snap in place, you just can swipe along.

and if you have js disabled, at least you can use the scroll wheel :)

Thx for help and tips.

Comment: Such a question is too broad. You have to simply search Google and demo a bunch of sliders to find one that meets most of your needs.